# How to change http into https using camel restlet

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel, rest-client

Hi Guys currently i am working in a project based on camel and java.There came a requirement likely to change **http** into **https**.
After doing lot of research i am able to expose my **restlet** into **https**.
But when i am trying to hit the url from restclient i am getting no response,even no errors.
When i am looking for the opening ports, i can find my port there.
I am sending my code and logs along with my code.
Please some one help me to resolve out this issue.

**Logs Generated**

```html
Mar 07, 2017 5:35:51 PM org.restlet.engine.connector.NetServerHelper start
INFO: Starting the internal [HTTPS/1.1] server on port 8060
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] RestletComponent               DEBUG Added method based router: org.apache.camel.component.restlet.MethodBasedRouter@7d6a41fe
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] RestletComponent               DEBUG Attached restlet uriPattern: /jsonRestlet method: POST
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] RestletComponent               DEBUG Attached methodRouter uriPattern: /jsonRestlet
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] RestletComponent               DEBUG Started methodRouter uriPattern: /jsonRestlet
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Route: route1 started and consuming from: Endpoint[https://localhost:8060/jsonRestlet]
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] ultManagementLifecycleStrategy DEBUG Load performance statistics disabled
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Total 1 routes, of which 1 are started.
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] SpringCamelContext             INFO  Apache Camel 2.17.2 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 1.302 seconds
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] MainSupport                    DEBUG Starting Spring ApplicationContext: org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@77575e6a
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] DefaultListableBeanFactory     DEBUG Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] ClassPathXmlApplicationContext DEBUG Publishing event in org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@77575e6a: org.springframework.context.event.ContextStartedEvent[source=org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@77575e6a: startup date [Tue Mar 07 17:35:49 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy]
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] DefaultListableBeanFactory     DEBUG Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'camel-1'
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] SpringCamelContext             DEBUG onApplicationEvent: org.springframework.context.event.ContextStartedEvent[source=org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@77575e6a: startup date [Tue Mar 07 17:35:49 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy]
[pache.camel.spring.Main.main()] DefaultListableBeanFactory     DEBUG Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'camel-1'
```

**My Request**

```html
URL:: https://localhost:8060/jsonRestlet
Request body::{"name":"mdnoorshid"}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Configures the Camel Context -->

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

 <camel:sslContextParameters id="mySslContext">
  <camel:keyManagers keyPassword="bizruntime">
   <camel:keyStore resource="C:\\Users\\deepalisingh\\Desktop\\keystore.jks"
    password="bizruntime" />
  </camel:keyManagers>
  <camel:serverParameters clientAuthentication="WANT" />
 </camel:sslContextParameters>
    <bean id="sendPOST" class="com.bizruntime.CamelRestletHTTPS.HTTPSsendPost"></bean>

 <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <route>
   <from uri="restlet:https://localhost:8060/jsonRestlet?restletMethod=POST&amp;sslContextParameters=#mySslContext"/>
   <to uri="bean:sendPOST?method=sendPost" />
  </route>
 </camelContext>

</beans>
```

Comment: Where is the log?

Comment: HTTPS by default is 443

Comment: Hi @SoucianceEqdamRashti you can find the logs.Sorry i have forgot to attach logs.Thanks for your response.

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti can you just tell me how to get the response using same code

Answer (score 0):

With the current configuration.
You will have to import the ssl-certificates within your client.
As example, you could refer @kellen answering, how to do it with Chrome.. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate)